# OpenCL data transfer and DMA

Tags: opencl, gpu, amd-processor

In the AMD APP programming guide it is written that (p.no 4-15):

For transfers <=32 kB: For transfers from the host to device, the data is copied by the CPU 
to a runtime pinned host memory buffer, and the DMA engine transfers the 
data to device memory. The opposite is done for transfers from the device to 
the host.

Is the above DMA, the CPU DMA engine  or the GPU DMA engine?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is the GPU DMA engine since on some cards (e.g., NVIDIA) you can do simultaneous read and write (so this is a GPU capability and not a CPU capability).